# How increase image size with ng-click on angular js?

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I need to add an ng-click function on image,  when I click on it is must increase size and after when I left the mouse over come back to original size.

with css i have create this and run good when put mouse on image

```
 .images img{
  float: left;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
}

.images img:hover{
width: 30%;
height: 30%%;
transition: width 2s, height 4s
}
```

on the html i have

```
 <img ng-click="$ctrl.changeSize(img)" ng-src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"  />
```

i don't know what i must write on changeSize for change the size of image when i click on it.

I'd like to use ng-click event, how can call into function changeSize the css values ?

thanks.

Comment: did you try ng-class with a flag changing on click?

Comment: You can as well use query style with `angular.element(document).find('the element name').css({ 'width': '30%', 'height': '30%' });` this will be from your controller after triggering the function with `ng-click`

Comment: @ Vali how can use a flag on click into ng-class ?

Comment: @akinjide I'd like use values from .css and not put value of changing directly into .js

Answer (score 0):

The function needs to be in your controller.

```
function toggleSize() {
  angular.element(document).find('#img-responsive').css({ 'width': '30%', 'height': '30%' });
}

<img id="img-responsive" ng-click="$scope.toggleSize()" ng-src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"  />
```

Comment: thanks for this solution but i can't change the values from .css, every changing must be done into js. I'd like modify values from .css

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img ng-click="$ctrl.toggleSize()" ng-class="{little: $ctrl.littleSize, big: !$ctrl.littleSize}" ng-src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png"  />
```

And in your controller :

```
$ctrl.littleSize = true;

$ctrl.toggleSize = function() {
    $ctrl.littleSize = !$ctrl.littleSize;
}
```

Comment: i have try but not run https://plnkr.co/edit/C3ysRsXIxVEQ3YmffdG4?p=preview